# LaTeX package schule - How to make changes to the template

Tags: templates, xsim

I have discovered the wonderful `schule` package and would like to change the layout of the evaluation units. However, I have absolutely no idea how to make any changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    fach=Informatik,
    typ={ohne},
    module={Aufgaben, Bewertung},
    klausurtyp=klausur,
    farbig,
    %loesungen=folgend,
    %erwartungshorizontAnzeigen,
]{schule}

\begin{document}

\begin{aufgabe}
Gegeben sei das Dreieck $ABC$ mit \[ A(6|7|9) \qquad B(4|4|3) \qquad C(2|10|6) \]
    \begin{teilaufgaben}
        \teilaufgabe[6] Zeigen Sie, dass das Dreieck gleichschenklig aber nicht gleichseitig ist. 
        \teilaufgabe[4] Fertigen Sie ein Schrägbild des Dreiecks an.
        \teilaufgabe[2] Geben Sie einen Punkt $D$ an, so dass das Viereck $ABCD$ ein Parallelogramm ist. Begründen Sie Ihre Wahl kurz.
    \end{teilaufgaben}
\end{aufgabe}

\end{document}
```

provides

[image: Bild zum Code]

I would like to have the valuation units like in the following picture

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Language here is English, so … // In general the package manual is the first place to have a look. If you are lucky, the author already provided your option. If not, have a search here. With bad luck you need to add your solution yourself. // The beauty about Latex is that the \renew-macros allow dedicated overwrites. Have a look e.g. here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros. Many manuals document the package code, so … there you go. // Fallback solution: Just live with it, until you know Latex better. // Finally: Why not contacting the package author?

Comment: Though my remarks on the \renew macros are correct, the approach taken in package schule is a bit different. They use the (still experimental) xsim-package, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim . To display the various sheets they defined a couple of templates, found in /tex/latex/schule/xsim-style . For the syntax see said manual. // To modify your output, you'd need to come up with a template modification. For a novice in Latex this would be quite a task, in my view (requires knowledge of Tex, Latex, xsim, schule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    fach=Informatik,
    typ={ohne},
    module={Aufgaben, Bewertung},
    klausurtyp=klausur,
    farbig,
    %loesungen=folgend,
    %erwartungshorizontAnzeigen,
]{schule}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% Redefine the layout for subquestions
\RenewDocumentCommand\teilaufgabe{o}{
    \IfInsideSolutionTF{
        % In Lösungen
        \item%
    }{
        % In Aufgaben
        \item%
        \IfNoValueF{#1}{
            \marginnote{%
                \leavevmode
                \small\addpoints*{#1} #1 BE}%
        }
    }
}

% New Template for "aufgabe"
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{schule-rand} {%
    \addpenalty{-30}
    \smallskip\noindent\textbf{%
            % Falls Zusatzaufgabe:
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\ExerciseType}{zusatzaufgabe}}{\llap{\GetExerciseProperty{symbol}$\bigstar$}~}{\llap{\GetExerciseProperty{symbol}~}}%
            \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
            \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
            \IfInsideSolutionF{%
                \IfExercisePropertySetT{subtitle}{
                    {\nobreakspace\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{\normalfont \itshape \PropertyValue}}}% Subtitle setzten
                }%
        % Stil für Punkteanzeige
        \GetExercisePropertyTF{points}{%
            \normalfont% Punkte in normal font/Shape aber auf Ebene der Subsection
            \marginpar{%
      \textbf{\printgoal{\PropertyValue} BE}
            \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}
            {\nobreakspace\small(+\PropertyValue)}% Kleinere Bonuspunkte?
          } 
        }{%Keine Punkte
            \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{
                \normalfont% Punkte in normal font/Shape aber auf Ebene der Subsection
                \nobreakspace(0\nobreakspace\small(+\PropertyValue)% Kleinere Bonuspunkte?
                \nobreakspace%
                \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{bonus-points}
                    {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
                    {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
                )
            }
        }
    }\par\smallskip\nopagebreak
    %
    %
}
{\IfInsideSolutionT{\par}}%

\xsimsetup{aufgabe/template=schule-rand}

\begin{document}

\begin{aufgabe}
Gegeben sei das Dreieck $ABC$ mit \[ A(6|7|9) \qquad B(4|4|3) \qquad C(2|10|6) \]
    \begin{teilaufgaben}
        \teilaufgabe[6] Zeigen Sie, dass das Dreieck gleichschenklig aber nicht gleichseitig ist. 
        \teilaufgabe[4] Fertigen Sie ein Schrägbild des Dreiecks an.
        \teilaufgabe[2] Geben Sie einen Punkt $D$ an, so dass das Viereck $ABCD$ ein Parallelogramm ist. Begründen Sie Ihre Wahl kurz.
    \end{teilaufgaben}
\end{aufgabe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the closest you can get without changing anything:

- select one of the templates `schule-default`, `schule-randpunkte` or `schule-tcolorbox` (you can do it several times via `\setzeAufgabentemplate{}`)
- see sect. 3.1.3 in [1](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/schule/doc/schule.pdf).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}% Ok, KOMA Script
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}% <<< That also works

\usepackage[
    fach=Informatik,
    typ={ohne},
    module={Aufgaben, Bewertung},
    klausurtyp=klausur,
    farbig,
    %loesungen=folgend,
    %erwartungshorizontAnzeigen,
]{schule}


% =================================================
\begin{document}
% ~~~ default template ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\fbox{Template: schule-default}% <<< just to see it in the output

\setzeAufgabentemplate{schule-default}% <<< !
    \begin{aufgabe}
    Gegeben sei das Dreieck $ABC$ mit \[ A(6|7|9) \qquad B(4|4|3) \qquad C(2|10|6) \]
        \begin{teilaufgaben}
            \teilaufgabe[6] Zeigen Sie, dass das Dreieck gleichschenklig aber nicht gleichseitig ist. 
            \teilaufgabe[4] Fertigen Sie ein Schrägbild des Dreiecks an.
            \teilaufgabe[2] Geben Sie einen Punkt $D$ an, so dass das Viereck $ABCD$ ein Parallelogramm ist. Begründen Sie Ihre Wahl kurz.
        \end{teilaufgaben}
    \end{aufgabe}
\hrule\bigskip% <<< just for read-ability

% ~~~ default randpunkte ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setzeAufgabentemplate{schule-randpunkte}% <<< !%
\fbox{Template: schule-randpunkte}%  <<< just to see it in the output

    \begin{aufgabe}
    Gegeben sei das Dreieck $ABC$ mit \[ A(6|7|9) \qquad B(4|4|3) \qquad C(2|10|6) \]
        \begin{teilaufgaben}
            \teilaufgabe[6] Zeigen Sie, dass das Dreieck gleichschenklig aber nicht gleichseitig ist. 
            \teilaufgabe[4] Fertigen Sie ein Schrägbild des Dreiecks an.
            \teilaufgabe[2] Geben Sie einen Punkt $D$ an, so dass das Viereck $ABCD$ ein Parallelogramm ist. Begründen Sie Ihre Wahl kurz.
        \end{teilaufgaben}
    \end{aufgabe}
\hrule\bigskip% <<< just for read-ability


% ~~~ default tcolorbox ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\fbox{Template: schule-tcolorbox}% <<< just to see it in the output

\setzeAufgabentemplate{schule-tcolorbox}% <<< !
    \begin{aufgabe}
    Gegeben sei das Dreieck $ABC$ mit \[ A(6|7|9) \qquad B(4|4|3) \qquad C(2|10|6) \]
        \begin{teilaufgaben}
            \teilaufgabe[6] Zeigen Sie, dass das Dreieck gleichschenklig aber nicht gleichseitig ist. 
            \teilaufgabe[4] Fertigen Sie ein Schrägbild des Dreiecks an.
            \teilaufgabe[2] Geben Sie einen Punkt $D$ an, so dass das Viereck $ABCD$ ein Parallelogramm ist. Begründen Sie Ihre Wahl kurz.
        \end{teilaufgaben}
    \end{aufgabe}

\end{document}
```

To illustrate your task, if you insist on your intended result, here's a compare between `schule-default` and `schule-randpunkte` in PSPad:

[image: compare]

So, the best might be to contact the author(s) of package `schule` to raise a request: it might be interesting for other teachers, too. Perhaps his github account is the best way to do it via ["Activity"](https://gitlab.com/gi-fg-ibnw/schule/activity) (once you registered at github).

**References**:

- [schule manual](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/schule/doc/schule.pdf)
- [xsim manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/xsim-manual.pdf)